# Wordpress get_option() with index key from string

Tags: php, wordpress, string

--Edited--

I've made a admin form which adds some custom functions to my theme. Loading the settings page I first get the current settings from the database. For this I use `get_option()`.

The setting field is called `product_settings`
To get all values from this setting you can call it with: `$option = get_option('product_settings');`

The result of this is equivalent to this:

```
    $option = [
        'product_01' => [
            'style' => [
                'color' => [
                    'primary' => '#ffffff'
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ];
```

Now, to get the value of index 'primary' I would call it like this:

From DB:

```
$optionColorPrimary = get_option('product_settings')['product_01']['style']['color']['primary'];
```

From array:

```
$optionColorPrimary = $option['product_01']['style']['color']['primary'];
```

Now, this work all fine and that. But now comes the tricky part. The index location is passed in a string value like this:

```
$get_option_srt = 'product_settings[product_01][style][color][primary]';
```

First part is the db field. And the part after it, separated by square brackets are the nested indexes.

**My Question**
How do I get to the nested value of this array based on the indexes from the string?

This is my attempt so far:

```
$get_option_srt = 'product_settings[product_01][style][color][primary]';

// split in two, to separate the field name from the indexes.
$get_option_srt  = preg_split('/(\[.*\])/', $get_option_srt, 2, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE|PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

// yes, this does not work... 
// The part after get_option() is wrong. Here are the nested index locations needed
$option = get_option( $get_option_srt[0] )[ $get_option_srt[1] ];
```

Any help is welcome.

Comment: What is the actual option name in the database that you are trying to get? (It's hard to help you parse from one to the other without knowing what the ultimate end goal is)

Comment: Thanks @cale_b, I've edited my question. It was a bit messy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend *not* attempting to get it directly off the `get_option()` result, but rather get the value, then parse the path.

You can write your own function that accomplishes what you want.  Something like so:

NOTE: This has many "Defensive" measures in place, so that if you ask for a path that doesn't exist, or use a malformed path, this will not throw PHP notices / errors:

```
function get_option_by_path( $path ) {
    // get all the "keys" from within the square braces
    preg_match_all( '/\[(.+?)\]/', $path, $matches );
    // get the initial "key" (eg, 'product_settings')
    $key = explode( '[', $path );
    // ensure base key is set, in case there were no square braces
    $key = ( ! empty( $key[0] ) ) ? $key[0] : $key;
    // load the option value from the DB
    $option = get_option( $key );
    if ( ! $option || ! is_array( $option ) ) {
        return FALSE;
    }

    // if the passed-in path didn't have any square-brace keys, return the option
    if ( empty( $matches[1] ) ) {
        return $option;
    }

    // loop over all the keys in the square braces
    foreach ( $matches[1] AS $key ) {
        // if $option is an array (still), and has the path, set it as the new $option value
        if ( is_array( $option ) && array_key_exists( $key, $option ) ) {
            $option = $option[ $key ];
        } else {
            // otherwise, can't parse properly, exit the loop
            break;
        }
    }

    // return the final value for the $option value
    return $option;
}
```

Usage:

```
$get_option_srt = 'product_settings[product_01][style][color][primary]';
$value = get_option_by_path( $get_option_srt );
```

Comment: This is a very comprehensive answer. For me as a rookie very insightful. Thank you @cale_b

Comment: Glad I could help! Thanks for the comment.

Comment: I've changed the else in the foreach loop from break; to return FALSE; I found it returned it's parent array/values when the index it searches for doesn't (yet) exists.

Comment: That's a good option.  I chose `break;` not knowing for sure your desired handling of that scenario, so what you're talking about makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
$value = 'product_settings[product_01][style][color][primary]';
// The below should result in: 'product_settings[product_01[style[color[primary'
$key_string = str_replace(']', '', $value);
//Create an array for all the values, using '[' as the delimiter
$key_array = explode('[', $key_string);
/* Remove first value (the option name), and save the 
value (which is 'product_settings' in this case) */
$option_name = array_shift($key_array);
// Get the option value (an array) from the db:
$option_settings = get_option($option_name);

// Set $option_setting to be the entire returned array:
$option_setting = $option_settings;

/*
Iterate through your key array for as many keys as you have, 
changing $option_setting to be more refined on each iteration 
until you get the value you need:
*/
for ($i = 0; $i < count($key_array); $i++) {
    $option_setting = $option_setting[$key_array[$i]];
}
```

`$option setting` should now contain the value you need.

Comment: Yes, :) The one after the edit works like a charm. Thanks  @markmoxx
Also thanks for the comments within the code. Learned a few nice things from it.

Comment: Yes, I accidentally used the wrong array within the loop for your keys before the edit. I added the comments partially so I could be sure my logic made sense (I didn't test it!) And for your benefit of course :)